# PHP - fwrite()/fputs() Sometimes Messing Up Accented Characters

Tags: php, html, utf-8, fwrite

I have been working on a PHP program that at the end exports an HTML file. I am encountering an issue where *sometimes* French characters are not properly written to the file (it is not an issue with the webpage, I opened the file in notepad and the characters were just changed).

Here is the piece of code that I have written:

```
foreach($footer as $a){
echo $a;
fwrite($file, $a."\r\n");
}
```

The echo displays the following:

> En cas de divergence entre le présent document et les documents
>   contractuels officiels, ces derniers ont préséance.

But what is written to the file is:

> En cas de divergence entre le prÃ©sent document et les documents
>   contractuels officiels, ces derniers ont prÃ©sÃ©ance.

A couple lines above this in my code I export lines with other French characters and they work just fine (it is essentially exactly the same code), but here it is not.

I have tried using fputs(), changing fopen($file,'w') to fopen($file, 'wb'), adding utf_encode() (which just makes the mess that comes out look worse), etc. and nothing has fixed this issue. Any ideas?

Comment: Is  your phpscript file set to `utf8` too?

Comment: Or try something from the manual:
fwrite($file, utf8_encode($myString));

Comment: Also be sure that the  editor you are using to open the file after writing supports utf8 and is not set on latin1

Comment: Where does the value of variable `$a` come from? A database column?

Comment: mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8"); for PHP internal encoding. Make sure that your IDE uses utf8, else even if the content is utf8 you won't be able to see it.

Comment: I am using Notepad++ to open the file after (it displays the same thing as when I open the HTML file in my browser). Like I said I already tried utf8_encode(), which makes the output become: "En cas de divergence entre le prÃƒÂ©sent document et les documents contractuels officiels, ces derniers ont prÃƒÂ©sÃƒÂ©ance.".

Answer (score 0):

I ended up finding the solution to my problem:

I could not set  and stuff in the  at gets overwritten by another program that modifies the file that I do not have any control over so French characters have to be displayed in the text as is.

To display properly had to do

```
fwrite($file, utf8_decode($a)."\r\n");
```

Thanks everyone :)